# Solana Private Cluster - Can't Upgrade Program

Tags: cluster, private-node

Has anyone encountered this? I have a private cluster that is running in AWS.  I can deploy programs, but when I try and upgrade them all of the transactions go through the bpfupgradeloader with no final success confirmation.

So when I deploy the first time, the last log in bpf is :

````
  Signature: 493zS41jJN9mNqrU1kwRAeWWDPQwHBc8LwwnZRsfh1ZUS3wgiNXjLr4kiDjPszAe1KPckxLxRDsLZncLegwLTeMD
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]
    Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
    Deployed program 7qBuZai1LiV1whqmpSZeckcDtCnLZjwsfkYU8CWJWzML
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 success```

but when I upgrade I just get the transactions:

```    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 success
Transaction executed in slot 3793:
  Signature: H9wKmeX8eXiGpoyXVdws7veQNo4r3TF7yHPhEbXsL9YAWP4wPYyydYByHKxmVEYyYr86GLP6qTK5J7khdidvdu3
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 success
Transaction executed in slot 3793:
  Signature: 5nP5pek91NDiiBSZm29D4taBep5pTVcvGGW3p4nCcfuxXoBys7GpmWGh2kdyZueuZh77L11rL9syGyHtdsPcY7XP
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
    Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 success```

Has anyone seen this behavior?
````

Answer (score 1):

A program deployment takes many transactions, so there's likely more transactions past this, the final upgrade transaction should include the log:

```
Upgraded program <PROGRAM_ID>
```

So keep looking for that final upgrade instruction!

Taken from the bpf loader code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8a0c91d84258a991f842b0ed2a5d896a80b8dae9/programs/bpf_loader/src/lib.rs#L890

Comment: Thanks for responding.  That’s the log entry that’s not coming.  All the transactions are there (actually there are 600 approx of them so I haven’t counted but they look like they are there).  Works fast and fine on first deploy, per program ID.  I’m going to try an older version just for a sanity check.  Otherwise I’m stumped/. I’m temp just working around it by deploying to new program ID to upgrade but that’s a pain.

Comment: Ah darn, sorry. That's really strange behavior... if you happen to narrow down the cause, and it doesn't have to do with your setup, it might be worth a bug report